# GNU/Make. Одно правило для разных целей

Tags: makefile

Возможно ли в *GNU/Make* задать одно правило для разных целей?

Например, имею две цели (1 исполнимый файл): `targ0.axf` и `targ1.axf`. Оба зависят от одних объектных файлов, оба собираются одинаково:

```
targ0.axf: file0.o file1.o
    $(LD) $^ -o $@ $(LFLAGS)

targ1.axf: file0.o file1.o
    $(LD) $^ -o $@ $(LFLAGS)
```

Это можно записать как-то короче?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

да, можно. например, так:

```
targ0.axf targ1.axf: file0.o file1.o
    $(LD) $^ -o $@ $(LFLAGS)
```

Comment: Только надо не забыть указать обе цели, например в `all:` для полной сборки

Comment: @avp, это ценное замечание, правда не имеющее (прямого) отношения ни к вопросу, ни к ответу.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin , Большое спасибо. У меня еще вопрос, а что если цели targ0.axf и targ1.axf собираются одинаково, но зависимости у них разные?

Comment: @Reffum, тогда таким образом объединять нельзя. но, возможно, имена целей (targets) частично совпадают с именами зависимостей (prerequisites), тогда можно попробовать воспользоваться [static pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Pattern.html).